# Netty ByteToMessageDecoder can't be @sharable

Tags: multithreading, netty, serversocket, decoder

I use `MyDecoder` which extends `ByteToMessageDecoder` to get Message from the socket Stream.
It works fine in one thread. But in more threads, the netty has reported 'the handler should be sharable'
However, I search in netty api, the `ByteToMessageDecoder` can't be @sharable, so how can I use
it in multi thread.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new instance in your ChannelInitializer.

Comment: But why it is not @Sharable?

Comment: because it contains some state in the instance